# Переменная регулярное выражение nginx if()

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Есть такая часть конфигурации:

```
set $domain      "mysite.com";
set $subdomain   "www";

if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.$domain$) {
     set $subdomain $1;
}
```

Если зайти с поддомена переменная $subdomain все равно имеет значение "www".
Если в условии вместо $domain прописать mysite.com, то переменная $subdomain будет иметь значение поддомена. Есть ли вообще возможность добавить переменную в регулярное выражение такого рода?

Если да - что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: Это, [кажется, невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859848/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-a-nginx-if-regular-expression).

Comment: теперь уже и я так думаю